# Add array of picture into Mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have A Mongodb database structure below, I would like to add a `list of picture` into the structure :

```
{
    "_id": "50d3dbce1292dd2e98af1dd1",
    "Name": "Bubba",
    "Address": "1111",
    "Loc": {
        "Lon": 11.0000,
        "Lat": 3.113005
    },
    "Pic" : [{"Name": "test1.jpg", "Size":"1000"}, {"Name": "test2.jpg", "Size":"2000"}],
    "LastModified": {
        "$date": "2012-12-21T03:47:26.535Z"
    }
}
```

My model:

```
public class Test
    {
        [BsonId]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public Location Loc { get; set; }
        public Picure Pic {get; set; }
        public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public double Lon { get; set; }
        public double Lat {get; set;}
    }

    public class Picture
    {
        public string Name{ get; set;}
        public int Size {get; set;}
    }
```

Is my design for array of picture model correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your document `Pic` is an array. So, you should declare you `Pic` property as `List<Picture>`

```
public List<Picture> Pic {get; set; }
```

Also there is an error in your json:

```
{"Name", "test1.jpg", "Size":"1000"}
```

but should be

```
{"Name": "test1.jpg", "Size":"1000"}
```